# What does a negative PEG ratio indicate? Is it bad or very bad?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, stock-valuation, value-investing, ratio

As far as I know, if you're buying a stock with a PEG ratio less than 1, then it's a good valuation of that stock.

But I don't have any idea what a negative PEG indicates. Is it bad or very bad?

[Here](https://www.screener.in/screens/279183/Company-of-Better-Valuation-PEG-Ratio/?sort=PEG%20Ratio&order=asc) are many stocks that have a negative PEG ratio.

Answer (score 3):

a negative PEG (Price to Earnings Growth) ratio can mean one of two things: either the company's current earnings are negative, or its expected earnings growth rate is negative. Neither are desirable outcomes.

If a company's current earnings are negative, you should assess whether this is a short-term problem (e.g. brought about by one-off impairment or restructuring charges) or the sign of structural problems.

The same rules apply when it comes to assessing a company's expected earnings growth rate. However, it is fair to say that negative expected growth rates are usually a "red flag".

It also helps to compare a company's PEG ratio against that of its peers, to put a company's ratio in context.